# two functions to transfer characters in string to uppercase. one works the other fails to work. why?

Tags: c, string, uppercase, lowercase

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 73
void tobigletter(char *p);
int main(void)
{
    char ch1[SIZE];
    puts("Enter a string");
    gets(ch1);
    tobigletter(ch1);
    printf("ch1 = %s\n" , ch1);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void tobigletter(char *p)
{
    while(*p)
    {
        if(islower(*p))
            *p -= 32;
        p++;
    }
}
```

Look at the code above. The function tobigletter is used to transfer whatever is lowercase letter into capital letters. It works fine. Now I have written another function. I have no idea why it doesn't work.

```
void tobigletter(char *p)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(p) ; i++)
        if(islower(*(p + i))
            *p -= 32;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Write

```
 if(islower(*(p + i))
            *( p + i ) -= 32;
              ^^^^^^
```

But in any case it is better to use standard function `toupper` instead of the magic number `32`.

For example

```
 if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*( p + i ) ) 
     *( p + i ) = toupper( ( unsigned char )*( p + i ) );
```

Comment: ... or `p[i]`! And are the unsigned char casts necessary?

Comment: @immibis  "In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char" - C Standard.

Comment: @immibis If `p[i]` is negative, which `char` may be, `toupper()` is not necessarily defined expect for `EOF`.  The `unsigned char`cast is a common way to handle that.